# Memory leak on nodeJs strongloop strong supervisor

Tags: node.js, strongloop

Our node supervisor is having memory leak and it's getting crashed. For below memory it takes around 2 weeks before we get OOM error.

```
// boot script
start() { 
    cd ${APPDIR} 
    mkdir -p ${LOGDIR} 
    killall node 
    sleep 5 
    rm -rf ${APPDIR}/.tmp 
    (slc run --no-profile -d --cluster <%= @clusters %> --log ${LOGDIR}/${APP_NAME}.log -p ${LOGDIR}/${APP_NAME}.pid ${APPDIR}/${APP} --port **** --max-old-space-size=8192)    RETVAL=$?
```

Any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: Are you sure the problem is in the supervisor and not in your Node code?

Comment: NodeJS process  memory is stable , there is no growth observed. Memory growth is observed only on strongloop supervisor

Comment: How much memory is there on the system and what is the cluster size being set to?

Comment: it runs on AWS m3.large  7.5 GB ram. There are 3 instances in cluster